# SWIFT : expand / collapse custom cell from UIswitch in the custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch, custom-cell

In my `viewcontroller`,
I added my tableview (`@IBOutlet weak var MyTableView: UITableView!`) in which I added several custom cells with specific size depending on the elements needed inside.
I call each cell with `identifier` :

```
func tableView(_ MyTableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = MyTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstCell") as! FirstCell
        self.SettingsTableView.rowHeight = 220
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 { etc etc...
```

And at a specific row, I've added a UIswitch directly in the cell that should expand / collapse this cell depending if it's ON or OFF. 
I'd like to make it work a bit like the `SelectRowAtIndexPath` method and animate it to make appear 3 textFields below....

I'm looking for hours a solution, if you have any idea... Any suggestion is welcome !

[image: sketch of my tableview]

Answer (score 0):

If your switch is properly hooked up to the cell, the problem may be that you didn't refresh the UITableView, and thence it doesn't expand.